# How can I make font awesome icon vertically centered using css?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I can't figure out why the font awesome icons are aligned to the top of each box in the sidebar nav instead of vertical-center (see image)

[image: icon not aligned vertical-center]

This is the code I'm using but I keep getting the result in the image above

```css
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-left .leaflet-sidebar-tabs {
  left: 0;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-right .leaflet-sidebar-tabs {
  right: 0;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs,
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > li,
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul > li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 80ms;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > li:hover,
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul > li:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > li.active,
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul > li.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0074d9;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > li.disabled,
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul > li.disabled {
  color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > li.disabled:hover,
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul > li.disabled:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > li.disabled > a,
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul > li.disabled > a {
  cursor: default;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > li > a,
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.leaflet-sidebar-tabs > ul + ul {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I would like to know how I can vertically center the font awesome icons in its parent

Comment: Please share HTML too or create a Codepen.

Comment: Hi, I created the codepen here: https://codepen.io/floyd434/pen/xxwmKBq   Weird thing is it looks fine there. I can't for the life of me figure out why the icons are top-aligned...

Comment: Try to figure out if you used leaflet classes somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I just rewrote the whole thing and it looks fine now, no idea what I did wrong!!